# ActiveMQ TLS host hostname verifications

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ 5.15.6 they enabled the TLS host name verification, and I see my application failing after upgrade.

In [their documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5156-release) they mentioned they have fixed the server side TLS validation by making default to False. Is their any way I can make TLS hostname verification FALSE at client side as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can disable TLS hostname verification at the client side as well. Use something like this:

```
ssl://hostname:61616?socket.verifyHostName=false
```

or

```
ssl://hostname:61616?verifyHostName=false
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. It worked!!!.. Hope ActivieMQ documentation should add this .

Comment: It's documented under https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35862#SSLTransportReference-HostnameValidation(Startingwithversion5.15.6) but weirdly not under https://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference but again under https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/activemq/content/ssl-transport-reference.html

Comment: I updated https://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference to include this information.