# Connection between 2 Brokers via SSL ActiveMQ

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, broker

I am trying to create an ActiveMQ network which will be consisted of 2 local brokers. I have done the configuration as below. I am new to this and not sure what I am missing. I have provided same ks and ts to both the brokers.

```xml
    <networkConnectors>
              <networkConnector name="LinktoInstance1"
                                uri="static:(ssl://localhost:61616)"
                                duplex="false"
                                networkTTL="2"
                                dynamicOnly="true"/>
    </networkConnectors>

     <transportConnectors>
                <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?trace=true&amp;needClientAuth=true"/>
     </transportConnectors>

    <sslContext>
             <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.home}/SSL/broker.ks" keyStorePassword="##" trustStore="file:${activemq.home}/SSL/broker.ts" trustStorePassword="##"/>
     </sslContext>
```

I am getting the below error on both the brokers upon startup.

```
 WARN | Could not start network bridge between: vm://instance1 and: ssl://localhost:61617 due to: Connection refused: connect
 INFO | Network Connector DiscoveryNetworkConnector:LinktoInstance2:BrokerService[instance1] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (instance1, ID:XXXXX-8986975-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | Establishing network connection from vm://instance1 to ssl://localhost:61617
 INFO | Connector vm://instance1 started
 INFO | Error with pending remote brokerInfo on: ssl://localhost/127.0.0.1:61617 (Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed)
 INFO | instance1 Shutting down LinktoInstance2
 WARN | Could not accept connection from tcp://127.0.0.1:60937: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown)
 INFO | instance1 bridge to Unknown stopped
 INFO | Error with pending local brokerInfo on: vm://instance1#2 (peer (vm://instance1#3) stopped.)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PKIX path error usually means some sort of certificate chain is failing. It can be a CA or an intermediate certificate may not be sent from the remote side, or in the truststore properly, certificate expired, hostname mismatch, etc. Post the full stacktrace-- there should be a "Caused by:" with more details.

Tip: Setting -Djava.net.debug=ssl is super helpful in debugging certificate issues.

Lots of variations too:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake

-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=access:stack
```

OpenSSL command line also is super helpful in validating remote server is sending good certificate chains: [openssl to validate remote server](https://langui.sh/2009/03/14/checking-a-remote-certificate-chain-with-openssl/)

Answer (score 0):

My application also failed with `Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`

In my case the StackOverflow article [ActiveMQ TLS host hostname verifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376251/activemq-tls-host-hostname-verifications) solved my issue. I had to add `socket.verifyHostName=false` to the connect string of the client in order to be able to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1.

**Note**: In ActiveMQ 5.15.6 they enabled the TLS host name verification. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35862#SSLTransportReference-HostnameValidation(Startingwithversion5.15.6) for detalis.